# Swift Core Data NSPredicate

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

## What Am I Trying to Accomplish?

I have an app with three Core Data entities: Ingredients, Cookies, and CookieIngredients.

- Ingredients are eggs, milk, butter, etc. and a Bool indicating whether I have that ingredient in my kitchen.
- Cookies are chocolate chip, oatmeal raisin, etc.
- CookieIngredients are the units of each ingredient required for each cookie.

I want to be able to display which cookies I can make based on which ingredients I have indicated are in my kitchen.

## What Have I Done?

I've successfully gotten my app to a state where all of these entities are managed in Core Data and I'm able to flag ingredients as "in my kitchen" with no problem. I'm able to search on Cookies based on ingredients and title.

## Where Am I Stuck?

I've been unable to find any examples to help understand how to create an NSPredicate to limit my FetchedResultsController to only Cookies where all of the CookieIngredient's Ingredients are "in my kitchen". If this was a web application using a MySQL database, I'd be able to do this with some inner joins, but I have no idea how to achieve something similar -- or even if it's possible to do such a thing -- with Core Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution!

Here's the predicate that worked for me:

`NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(cookieIngredients, $X, $X.in_kitchen == true).@count == cookieIngredients.@count")`

Answer (score 2):

A predicate like the following should work:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ALL ingredients.inKitchen = YES")
```

This assumes your `Cookie` entity has an `ingredients` relationship, with a `boolean` flag named `inKitchen`.

Comment: I feel like you're right and that this should work. I _do_ have an `ingredients` relationship on `Cookie` and a `Boolean` flag on the `Ingredients` entity. But it's not working. I get `Unsupported predicate ALL items.in_kitchen == 1`. The predicate looks like this: `NSPredicate(format: "ALL items.in_kitchen = true")` Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: FYI: I tried changing it to == instead of = but still no dice.

Answer (score 2):

If you are fetching `Cookie` objects, then the predicate needs to traverse both the (to-many) relationship to `CookieIngredient` and, from there, the (to-one) relationship to `Ingredient`.  So the predicate should be something like:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ALL cookieIngredients.ingredient.inKitchen = YES")
```

This assumes the relationship from `Cookie` to `CookieIngredient` is called "cookieIngredients" and the relationship from `CookieIngredient` to `Ingredient` is called "ingredient").

I find CoreData's parsing of to-many relationships (ie. ANY, ALL, NONE, SOME) a little unpredictable so I tend to use SUBQUERY to get the result I want.  In the above case, (noting that ALL inKitchen = YES is equivalent to saying none have inKitchen = NO) I would use:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(cookieIngredients, $X, $X.ingredient.inKitchen == NO).@count == 0")
```

Comment: I tried the first version with `NSPredicate(format: "ALL cookieIngredients.in_kitchen == true")` and it just throws the `Unsupported predicate ALL` error. In this case `cookieIngredients` is the relationship on the Cookie entity to the Ingredients entity. \n I also tried the second version as `NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(cookieIngredients, $X, $X.in_kitchen == false).@count == 0")` and that doesn't crash, but it also doesn't return the right Cookies. It does not return _all_ the cookies in the system, but it does return a bunch of cookies for which I don't have all the ingredients.

Comment: Here's a thought: The relationship from the Cookie entity to the Ingredient entity is currently configured as "to-many" at both ends, because one cookie can have many ingredients and one ingredient can be used in many cookies. Do I have that wrong? Should it only be set as "to-many" in one direction?

Comment: I'm getting confused about your model - can you edit your question to include a pic?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b21s23kcx18l2xj/Screenshot%202017-12-11%2016.58.14.png?dl=0

Comment: Thanks - I was mixing up the direct many-many relationship with the relationship via the intermediate Recipe entity.  But I see you found the right combination!